# How can I make a bootable USB ubuntu live disk for a Mac using Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb, mac

I've found guides that explain how to make a bootable disk for macs using macs, but I want to use ubuntu to make this mac-bootable disk. Is there a way to do that?

In other words, I have:

- a laptop that runs only ubuntu
- a 4GB usb thumb drive
- a Mac Mini 5,1 with non-working OSX Lion

and I'd like to install ubuntu on the Mac Mini.

I tried following the instructions here: http://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/

but the mediafire download that this guide requires is no longer available, and I can't find it anywhere else. So that's out.

Comment: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD564ZM/A/apple-usb-superdrive

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am responding to a four year old question, but what the heck, why not.

Use [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to "burn" an Ubuntu ISO to the flash drive. You can then boot from it on the Mac.